# EmguCV/OpenCV Image addition/subtraction

Tags: c#, image, opencv, subtraction, emgucv

I am using EmguCV and am trying to subtract 2 images to create a filter similar to AForge .NET's [MoveTowards](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f7f4ad2c-fb50-a76b-38fc-26355e0eafcf.htm) filter.

This is what my slightly modified version from the above URL tries to do. Given 2 images, the source and the overlay - it slowly moves the source image towards the overlay. It does this based on the following:

```
result = source + movementFactor * (overlay - source);
```

where result, source and overlay are images and movementFactor is the rate of change in the range 0 to 1.

When I tried this in code with movementFactor equal to 1, the results looked messed up (there was something like a motion trail). To test it further, I removed movementFactor from the above equation, and made result = source + overlay - source. I expected to see the overlay image as the result, which I did, but along with one region of the image that was flashing.

I am guessing that pixel intensities get clipped in the upper or lower bounds when addition/subtraction takes place.

I can accomplish what I want with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < src.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < src.Width; j++)
    {
        res[i, j] = new Gray(src[i, j].Intensity + movementFactor * (ovr[i, j].Intensity - src[i, j].Intensity));
    }
}
```

But this significantly slows down the processing. How can I overcome the addition/subtraction problem or the speed problem with the above? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post the answer I found over here, in case someone runs across the same issue in the future.

This is how you would do it:

```
Image<Gray,Byte> result = new Image<Gray,Byte>(source.Size);
CvInvoke.cvAddWeighted(source, 1.0-movementFactor, overlay, movementFactor, 0.0, result);
```

Source: EmguCV's forums, here is the [post](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=820&p=2076#p2095) that gave me the reply

Answer (score 1):

> I will post the answer I found over here, in case someone runs across
>   the same issue in the future.
>
> This is how you would do it:
>
> ```
> Image<Gray,Byte> result = new Image<Gray,Byte>(source.Size);
> CvInvoke.cvAddWeighted(source, 1.0-movementFactor, overlay, movementFactor, 0.0, result);
> ```
>
> Source: EmguCV's forums, here is the
>   post that gave me the reply

Note that there is a cleaner syntax for that:

```
var result = frame.AddWeighted(1.0 - movementFactor, overlay, movementFactor, 0.0);
```